# How to completely uninstall LMMS?

Tags: software-installation, purge, lmms

I installed LMMS a few months ago but now I want to uninstall it. My problem is that when I installed it, it took a few hundreds of MB's, but now, when I run `sudo apt purge lmms`, I can only get 14 MB free. I thus suspect there where other apps installed with it at the same time. In addition, I saw other logos appear near the logo of LMMS itself just after installation:

[image: logos appearing near LMMS]

I don't know how I get them away. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `sudo apt autopurge` and if that's not enough, look to remove the suggested and recommended packages that lmms installed. Also look in `/var/log/dpkg.log` to know which packages were and are to be un- installed

Comment: I added the second duplicate link because you asked about the topic, but I would prefer legacy apt-get instead of aptitude for this task because it's a very reasonable and security-conscious option.

Comment: Thank you for your answers !